# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of undefined not sure why it's happening

Tags: javascript, html

Not sure why this error is occurring, could anyone give me a helping hand please? I tried to add window.onLoad = function check() {} which still gave me the error code. I've double checked the code :/

```
check   @   errors.html:43
onclick @   errors.html:18
```

`

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Errors</title>
</head>

<body>
<p>Your password should containt atleast 6 characters, 1 number and 1 capital letter!</p>
    <p>Password: <br /> <input id="password" type="password"></p>
    <p>Re-enter Password: <br /> <input id="password2" type="password"><br /></p>
    <button onclick="check()">Submit</button>
    <br />
    <p id="error"></p>
    <script>
        function check() {
            var password = document.getElementById("password").value;
            var password2 = document.getElementById("password2").value;
            var errorMessage = document.getElementById("error").value;
            var errorToThrow = "";

            try {
                if (password.length < 6) {
                    errorToThrow += "<br /> Passsword too short.";
                }
                if (/[A-Z]/g.test(password) == false) {
                    errorToThrow += "<br /> Passsword needs 1 capital letter.";
                }
                if (/\d/g.test(password) == false) {
                    errorToThrow += "<br /> Passsword needs 1 digit.";
                }
                if (password != password2) {
                    errorToThrow += "<br /> Passwords should match.";
                }
                throw errorToThrow;
            } catch(err) {
                errorMessage.innerHTML = err;
            }
        }
</script>
</body>
</html>`
```

Comment: `errorMessage` is a string as it's the element's value, not an element. In this case, `p` doesn't have property `value` thus it is undefined, throwing the error. Perhaps you meant to do `document.getElementById("error").innerHTML`?

Comment: @AndrewLi that wouldn't work either.

Answer (score 1):

```
        var errorMessage = document.getElementById("error").value;
```

Looks like you copy/pasted, but the error message `<p>` won't have a "value" attribute, and even if it did you don't want that; you want the node itself:

```
        var errorMessage = document.getElementById("error");
```

Comment: I didn't copy and paste, and I literally saw and then read your comment lol, thank you for confirming.

Comment: I didn't copy and paste, and I literally saw the mistake and then read your comment lol, thank you for confirming.*

Comment: @CharlieClark lol well OK, in any case that I think is the issue.